# Concatenating several fields into a single field and linking in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I've got a table, GeoTable, which I need to perform a particular operation on.

The table has two main fields that I'm interested in. As this is a mapping project, there is the Geo field (which is a varchar(max) describing the geometry of a location in a string of latitudes and longitudes), and also the ID field (which is a bigint).

However, multiple IDs can have the same Geo (as one place could have been sold many times, for instance) and I need a query which groups them together and tells me which IDs each Geo has. So, for instance:

```
Geo                                             IDs
(My big Geometry string here)                   1
(My big Geometry string here)                   2
(My big Geometry string here)                   3
(My big Geometry string here)                   4
(My big Geometry string here)                   5
(My other big Geometry string here)             6
(My other big Geometry string here)             7
(My other big Geometry string here)             8
```

... becomes...

```
Geo                                             IDs
(My big Geometry string here)                   1,2,3,4,5,
(My other big Geometry string here)             6,7,8,
```

I've got some code here which is basically what I need, but it runs really slow (I'll be fetching about 20000 records at a time, but online through a website where people expect it pretty much instantly):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Geo, (
        SELECT ','+LEFT(CAST(G2.Id AS NVARCHAR),11) AS [text()]
        From dbo.GeoTable G2
        Where G2.Geo = GeoTable.Geo
        ORDER BY Id
        For XML PATH ('')
    ) [IDs]
FROM            GeoTable
```

Sorry, should also mention I'm using MS SQL Server, so no GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: I added the SQL Server code, assuming this is the actual database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ('My big Geometry string here)      ', 1),
    ('My big Geometry string here)      ', 2),
    ('My big Geometry string here)      ', 3),
    ('My big Geometry string here)      ', 4),
    ('My big Geometry string here)      ', 5),
    ('My other big Geometry string here)', 6),
    ('My other big Geometry string here)', 7),
    ('My other big Geometry string here)', 8)
    ) T(Geo, ID)
)
SELECT DISTINCT Geo, IDs
FROM Src S
CROSS APPLY (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ','+CONVERT(varchar(10),S2.ID)
                           FROM Src S2
                           WHERE S.Geo=S2.Geo
                           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')) T(IDs)
```

**Result**

```
Geo                                 IDs
-------------                       ----------
My big Geometry string here)        1,2,3,4,5
My other big Geometry string here)  6,7,8
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting... just trying to get it to work with my code.

Comment: Unfortunately, whilst a good solution, it is too slow for my needs. Think I'll have to figure out another way around this, possibly in client-side code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need group_concat

check here

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned I'm using MS SQL Server so GROUP_CONCAT is out (I have looked at that before though). But you get an upvote anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a variable to store the occurrences of each string and display them only once using distinct clause